# Is there an "automatic-null" operator for undefined index on an array in PHP?

Tags: php

I've been finding that I'm writing a lot of code like this:

```
$customData1 = $user['custom_data_1'] ?? null;
$customData2 = $user['custom_data_2'] ?? null;
$customData3 = $user['custom_data_3'] ?? null;
```

It seems like there should be some kind of simpler syntax for this.

I'd love for this to work without error:

`$customData1 = $user['custom_data_1'];`

And `$customData1` would be `null` if the index is not defined. But this presents a PHP error. Is there something similar to this:

`$customData1 = $user['custom_data_1']?;`

I understand using `??` when the fallback is something less unusual, but `null` is quite common and I don't see why there isn't a default for this operator.

I know I could also do this:

```
$user = (object) $user;
$customData1 = $user->custom_data_1;
$customData2 = $user->custom_data_2;
$customData3 = $user->custom_data_3;
```

But this kind of goes beyond what I'm actually trying to find an answer for.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using a function to initialise a variable if it not set - PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20774783/using-a-function-to-initialise-a-variable-if-it-not-set-php)

Comment: I am looking for built-in PHP functionality. I'm now thinking it doesn't exist.

Comment: At least, with `?? null`, you're explicitly stating that you expect the index to not exist. Explicit code is always better. If PHP didn't throw a warning when a key didn't exist, then you could easily miss typos on keys, among other things. Now in most cases you're better off using objects/DTOs (very basic objects), so your properties would exist anyway and have a default value.

Comment: Note: you could do `$customData1 = @$user['custom_data_1'];` (which is pretty much what you're looking for). But, seriously, don't :)

Comment: @Jeto: no, it really isn't what he's looking for... Warnings will be still generated and page will be slower. Only one right approach is to solve warning, not to close eyes before them.

Comment: @pavel Did you even read my comments? I clearly mentioned this was a very bad idea. However, this is *exactly* what he's asking, so I was pointing it out anyway. And no, the warning (notice) won't be neither displayed nor logged, that's the whole idea behind the error control operator.

Answer (score 0):

If you're still willing to consider involving objects, just not the one you mentioned, the you can implement the predefined interface `ArrayAccess`. Something like:

```
class stdArray implements ArrayAccess
{
    private $container = [];

    public function __const(array $array = [])
    {
        $this->container = $array;
    }

    ...

    public function offsetGet($offset)
    {
        return $this->container[$offset] ?? null;
    }

    ...

    // So we don't have to instantiate a new Object for each array if we don't need to.
    // Just me mindful though :P
    public function replace(array $array)
    {
        return $this->container = $array;
    }
}
```

For example:

```
$arr = new stdArray($user);
$customData1 = $user['custom_data_1'];
$customData2 = $user['custom_data_2'];
$customData3 = $user['custom_data_3'];
```

```
$arr = new stdArray();
foreach ($multiArray as $subArray) {
    $arr->replace($subArray);
    $customData1 = $arr['custom_data_1'];
    $customData2 = $arr['custom_data_2'];
    $customData3 = $arr['custom_data_3'];

    // Do some operations ...
}
```

Haven't actually tested this, but this might/should work.